# how to use apply family instead of nested for loop for my problem

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I want to fill a new data frame called `hd5` based on a conditions from a old data frame called `dfnew1`.

Can I do it without a nested `for` loop ?

```
   for(  j in 2 : length(hd6)  )
   {
     for( i in 1: length(hd5$DATE) )
    {
     abcd= dfnew1 %>%  
     filter( (Date == hd5$DATE[i]) , (StrikePrice== hd6[j]) , (OptionType== "CE"))  %>%
     arrange( dte  )          
     hd5[i,j]= abcd[1,9]
     }
   }
```

hd6= [13900,14000,14100,14200]

dfnew1 looks like this

```
Date     expiry     optiontype strikeprice closeprice  dte
1/1/2019  31/1/2019  ce          13900      700        30
1/1/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14000      650        30
1/1/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14100      600        30
1/1/2019  31/2/2019  ce          14100      900        58
1/2/2019  31/1/2019  ce          13900      800        29
1/2/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14000      750        29
1/2/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14100      700        29
```

i want to fill my new dataframe hd5 from this dfnew1 dataframe by maching the date and strtkeprice and optiontype

hd5 which i want to filled should look like

```
Date         13900  14000 14100 14200
1/1/2019     700     650   600   550
1/2/2019     800     750   700   650
```

Comment: Could you please add (a) some representative data from `hd5` - say, 5 - 10 lines, and (b) what you want `hd6` to look like?

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking that you edit your post so that we can see what `hd5` looks like, and what you _want_ `hd6` to look like.

Comment: do you have 3 datasets i.e hd6, hd5  along with dfnew1

Comment: yes. i have 3 datasets.

Comment: arrange( dte  ) . this i do because after filterind based on date and strike price and option type  i will get 3 rows with same date. so  i arrange them in ascending order. and select the 1st row by doing   hd5[i,j]= abcd[1,9]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: @r2evans   is it correct now??

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Hammysidhu. I've suggested an edit to format data as code, which can make a big difference for readability. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help if you want more info there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse option:

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Date, strikeprice) %>%
  summarize(closeprice = min(closeprice)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "strikeprice", values_from = "closeprice")
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Date     `13900` `14000` `14100`
#   <chr>      <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1 1/1/2019     700     650     600
# 2 1/2/2019     800     750     700
```

(You might see online tutorials referencing `tidyr::spread`. It does effectively the same thing here, but has been [retired](https://www.tidyverse.org/lifecycle/#retired) (source: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html, along with `tidyr::gather`), so it is generally recommended that new code should use the `pivot_*` functions.)

Note: based on your expected output, it looks like you took the minimum for

```
1/1/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14100      600        30
1/1/2019  31/2/2019  ce          14100      900        58
```

I might be more inclined (when "price" is involved) to use `sum` instead, but it depends heavily on your actual intent and use. Replace `min` with your aggregation of choice, be it `max`, `sum`, or something else.

I'll note that having numeric column names is a little non-standard, and can cause confusion (`dat[,14100]` will fail, `dat[,\`14100`]`or`dat[,"14100"]` should generally work).

You may find that having numeric column headers makes sense for some comparisons and for depicting a *table*, but if you plan on plotting things (e.g., using `ggplot2`), often a longer version (your original layout, summarizing notwithstanding) might be preferred.

---

Data:

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
Date     expiry     optiontype strikeprice closeprice  dte
1/1/2019  31/1/2019  ce          13900      700        30
1/1/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14000      650        30
1/1/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14100      600        30
1/1/2019  31/2/2019  ce          14100      900        58
1/2/2019  31/1/2019  ce          13900      800        29
1/2/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14000      750        29
1/2/2019  31/1/2019  ce          14100      700        29")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `spread` after summarizing to get the `min` of 'closeprice' after grouping by 'Date', 'strikeprice'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Date, strikeprice) %>%
  slice(which.min(dte)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(strikeprice, closeprice)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Date     `13900` `14000` `14100`
#  <chr>      <int>   <int>   <int>
#1 1/1/2019     700     650     600
#2 1/2/2019     800     750     700
```

---

Or using `pivot_wider` by making use of `values_fn` to pass a function.  Here, we `select` only the column of interest

```
dat %>%
  select(Date, strikeprice, closeprice) %>%     
  pivot_wider(names_from = strikeprice, values_from = closeprice,
       values_fn = list(closeprice = min))
# A tibble: 2 x 4   
#  Date     `13900` `14000` `14100`
#  <chr>      <int>   <int>   <int>
#1 1/1/2019     700     650     600
#2 1/2/2019     800     750     700
```

---

Or another option is `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), Date  ~ strikeprice, min, value.var = 'closeprice')
#       Date 13900 14000 14100
#1: 1/1/2019   700   650   600
#2: 1/2/2019   800   750   700
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2019", "1/1/2019", "1/1/2019", "1/1/2019", 
"1/2/2019", "1/2/2019", "1/2/2019"), expiry = c("31/1/2019", 
"31/1/2019", "31/1/2019", "31/2/2019", "31/1/2019", "31/1/2019", 
"31/1/2019"), optiontype = c("ce", "ce", "ce", "ce", "ce", "ce", 
"ce"), strikeprice = c(13900L, 14000L, 14100L, 14100L, 13900L, 
14000L, 14100L), closeprice = c(700L, 650L, 600L, 900L, 800L, 
750L, 700L), dte = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 58L, 29L, 29L, 29L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: i do not want min(close). i want close price corresponding to  min(dte).